# Github deploy key

Tags: git, github

I'm trying to use a deploy key on my server. I added the server public key as a deploy key on the repo on github. Running `ssh -T git@github.com` succeeds `Hi {username}/{repo}! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.`

But when trying a git pull it fails

```
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

The origin url is set to `git@github.com:{username}/{repo}.git`

Not sure what I'm doing wrong?

Edit, solved: my .git directory was owned by root which was causing the problem. Set ownership to another user and it works perfectly.

Comment: Is there a difference between the way you are executing `ssh -T git@github.com` and `git pull`? E.g. with a different user, or via `cron` or something? (I wouldn't advise running `git pull` via `cron` at all, if that's what you're doing.)